# AWS-Load Balancer. Does it incur cost when no EC2 is linked to them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As the title says, does ELB incur cost when no instance of EC2 is linked to it. I don't mean an instance of EC2 being "stopped", i mean when no ec2 is registered under ELB.

If ELB still incur cost, is there a way for me to stop the cost incurring without deleting the ELB? I don't want to have to configure an ELB every time I need to use it. FYI, i'm just in the process of developing so I don't need ELB EC2 to any other service up 24 hrs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Citing from https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/

> $0.025 per Elastic Load Balancer-hour (or partial hour)
>
> $0.008 per GB of data processed by an Elastic Load Balancer

Meaning that even ELB does not have any instance attached, you'll be charged on hourly basis.

You can use Cloudformation to create your ELB. By this way you'll have a JSON file including the whole configuration of your ELB and whenever you are not using it, you can just remove the Cloudformation stack to get rid of resources and create again with 1-click whenever you need it.

The best practice in AWS is to configure the whole structure using Cloudformation by the way.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. I've been incurring a lot of unwanted, unexpected cost so I'm trying to understand the whole billing situation here.

Comment: If you don't  mind, do you have time for one more question? Does elastic beanstalk restart your ec2 instance automatically? I tried to turn off my ec2 instance, but it seems like it just automatically turns it back on. Is this an expected elastic beanstalk behavior or is something else causing this? FYI, I have turned of Load Balancing and autoscaling. Thank you.

Comment: Of course it will create a new EC2 instance if you manually kill one. It's designed to do like that. Think that your instance stopped working, then it is creating a new one to keep your application running. If you do not want any running instance, you should set your autoscaling group parameter like this: Minimum Instance Size:0 Desired Instance Size:0, so autoscaling group will keep your instance count at 0.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply sir. So basically, under my elastic beanstalk settings, i will have load balancing off but auto scaling on, configured to what u suggested.

Comment: I do have an rds instance on which was set up while i was creating my ebs environment. Will this prevent me from turning off my ec2 instance?

Comment: 2022 Update: best practice is not cloudformation any more. Arguably using terraform is better.